# sh: add command string ourtput to array

Tags: sh

In `sh` I want to create an array with one element that is the curent date and time formatted with spaces.

```
$ date +"%b %d %H:%m"
Jun 23 16:06
```

Here are some things that don't work:

```
$ date +"%b %d %H:%m"
Jun 23 16:06
$ d=`date +"%b %d %H:%m"`
$ echo $d
Jun 23 16:06
$ arr=($d)
$ echo ${#arr}
3
$ arr=("$d")
$ echo ${#arr}
12
$ arr=("`date +"%b %d %H:%m"`")
$ echo ${#arr}
12
$ arr=(`date +"%b %d %H:%m"`)
$ echo ${#arr}
3
$ echo ${arr[2]}

$
```

Comment: Standard sh doesn't support arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You have a working solution already, but merely misinterpreted the test:

```
$ d=$(date +"%b %d %H:%m")
$ a=("$d")
$ echo ${#a[*]}
1
$ echo ${#a}  # Gives length of ${a[0]}, not number of elements in the array
12
$ a=("$d" "second entry")
$ echo ${a[0]}
Jun 23 16:06
$ echo ${a[1]}
second entry
$ echo ${#a[*]}
2
```

Answer (score 0):

The strangeness is because these three things are sometimes different:

1. `${#arr}`
2. `${#arr[*]}`
3. `${#arr[@]}`

Also, it's impossible to change `IFS`

```
# echo $IFS

# IFS="."
# echo $IFS

#
```

Comment: You can change IFS: `echo "$IFS"`, you just can't pass it as an argument to `echo` if you fail to quote it.